# RegEx to exclude a words

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have the following text:

```
123 = Fetch.fetch (Fetch.Method "GET") headers (Fetch.URI {parts})
123 = Fetch.fetch (Fetch.Method "POST") headers (Fetch.URI {parts}) (Just (encodeJSON reqBody))
```

And I want to get the following:

```
GET
POST encodeJSON
```

i.e. get the request method and if there is an "encodeJSON" string then leave it there; At the moment I do this in two steps:

1 `.*Fetch.Method "(.*)".*(\((.*) reqBody).*`
replace the text with $1 and $3 group.

I get `POST encodeJSON`.

2 `.*Fetch.Method "(.*)".*`
replace the text with $1 group.

I get a `GET`.

this works, but can it be done in one step, i.e., with a single regular expression?

Comment: If you are OK to have a trailing space after `GET` then it is possible, `^.*?Fetch\.Method "(.*?)"(?:.*(\((.*) reqBody))?.*` and replace with `$1 $3` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/vN3t0V/1/)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 capturing groups instead of 3, and use `$1` and `$2` in the replacement and make the last part for group 2 optional.

```
.*Fetch\.Method "([^"]+)"(?:.*\(([^()]*) reqBody)?.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nb2AbY/1)

A few notes about the pattern you tried:

Escape the `\.` to match it literally, and consider using a non greedy `.*?` or a negated character class to prevent over matching or unnecessary backtracking.

[image]

Comment: Since there is a nearby `space` you can grab that in a separate group, so that you don't get the unnecessary trailing space (if that is a problem).  See https://regex101.com/r/nb2AbY/3 for a slight modification of this regex and replace.